# How to send an email with java

Tags: jakarta-mail, sendmail

I know that there are many question like this but they didn't work for me
so if there is any way to send an email with java
(yahoo, hotmail or gmail)

Comment: can you post your code??

Comment: What didn't work for you? What have you tried? Are you serious asking us without giving any details?

Comment: Google it... learn how others so.. show some examples and explain why they did not work.. else google freelance

Comment: I think it was variable two on line twelve

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry guys the problem was on my Antivirus, I just turn it off and it work, this is the code. .... Don't forget to turn the Antivirus off

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendFrom
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{    
    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned

     String from = "YourEmail@gmail.com";//

     String pass ="YourPassword";
    // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
   String to = "DestinationEmail";
   String host = "smtp.gmail.com";


   // Get system properties
   Properties properties = System.getProperties();
   // Setup mail server
   //props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", host);
   //properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
   properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
   properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
   properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
   properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
   properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
   properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   properties.put("mail.debug", "true");

   // Get the default Session object.
   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

   try{
      // Create a default MimeMessage object.
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

      // Set From: header field of the header.
      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

      // Set To: header field of the header.
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                               new InternetAddress(to));

      // Set Subject: header field
      message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

      // Now set the actual message
      message.setText("This is actual message");

      // Send message
      Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
      transport.connect(host, from, pass);

      transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
      transport.close();
      System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
   }catch (MessagingException mex) {
      mex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
}
```